# hql dosenot see the updates

Tags: hibernate, hql, seam

I have two apps with shared DB 
the problem is that when updating a record from an app and after HQL query from the other app it dosenot get the new updates , is that by caching?

**The technologies we use**
seam , vaadin, jpa/hibernate

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class"   value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
            value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
```

hql:
from User

Answer (score 0):

Are your methods that store the data annotated with @Transactional or whatever is the Seam equivalent (or if you are using programmatic transactions, are you creating and committing a transaction)? I seem to recall that methods storing data to database with no @Transactional (using Spring) would cause no exceptions or other errors, but wouldn't simply ever commit the data into the database. Also flushing the transaction/db session might help.

Comment: Data is already committed . the problem recall the query after updating by other apps

Comment: You could try entityManager.clear() (if using JPA EntityManager), or session.clear() if using "raw" Hibernate sessions before your query to force the first-level cache to be cleared. If memory serves, both JPA EntityManager and Hibernates' Session-object should also have refresh(obj) -method, which forces a refresh all the way from database, bypassing first- and second-level caches. When not using the caches, you're likely to see some performance hit (which could be very minor or very high, depending on your db usage, query sizes etc.).